# Why don't WolframAlpha's and Sage's answers match?

Tags: sage, wolframalpha

Consider this input to WolframAlpha,

solve [ 0 = x^4 - 6*x^2 - 8*x*cos( (2*pi )/5 ) - 2*cos( (4*pi)/5) - 1 ]

The solutions it gives are,

{x == (1 - Sqrt[5])/2 || x == (3 + Sqrt[5])/2 || x == (-2 - Sqrt[2 (5 - Sqrt[5])])/2 || x == (-2 + Sqrt[2 (5 - Sqrt[5])])/2}

But the same equation on sage gives the roots,

h(x) = x^4 - 6*x^2 - 8*x*cos( (2*pi )/5 ) - 2*cos( (4*pi)/5) - 1

h(x).solve(x)

[x == -1/2*sqrt(-2*sqrt(5) + 10) - 1, x == 1/2*sqrt(-2*sqrt(5) + 10) -
1, x == -1/2*sqrt(2*sqrt(5) + 6) + 1, x == 1/2*sqrt(2*sqrt(5) + 6) + 1]

It seems that the first two roots given by WolframAlpha differ from the last two roots given by Sage.

Why?

Answer (score 2):

They're not different; they're exactly the same, simply listed in a different order.

```
sage: h(x) = x^4 - 6*x^2 - 8*x*cos( (2*pi )/5 ) - 2*cos( (4*pi)/5) - 1
sage: sols = h(x).solve(x, solution_dict=True)
sage: [CC(d[x]) for d in sols]
[-2.17557050458495, 0.175570504584946, -0.618033988749895, 2.61803398874989]
sage: wa = [ (1 - sqrt(5))/2 ,  (3 + sqrt(5))/2 ,  (-2 - sqrt(2* (5 - sqrt(5))))/2 ,  (-2 + sqrt(2* (5 - sqrt(5))))/2 ]
sage: [CC(v) for v in wa]
[-0.618033988749895, 2.61803398874989, -2.17557050458495, 0.175570504584946]
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this technique getting decimal representations to check!